# how to Select a hidden sub menu in selenium Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am new to selinum , during mouse hover(Request button) two button will be display on the screen.

```
1.User Status button
2. confirm user button
```

On click of  User status button particular javascript function should be trigger..

I tried the below code, but it doesn't work.

```
WebElement subMenu = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu']/ul/li[2]/a"));
actions.moveToElement(subMenu);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

**HTML Structure :-**

```
<div id="menu">         
        <ul id="MenuBar"> 
                <li id="MainLink">
                    <a href="javascript:add();">add</a>
                </li> 
                <li id="MainLink"><a>Requests</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:check();">User Status</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:confirm();">Confirm User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
                <li id="PrimaryLink">
                   <a href="javascript:update();">Update</a>
                    <ul></ul>
                </li>                    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step-wise solution to your Question:

1. Locate the `Request` button & store the element:

   ```
   WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_request_button"));
   ```
2. Use Actions class to hover over the `Request` button:

   ```
   Actions act = new Actions(driver);
   act.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
   ```
3. Create a list using `findElements` to match the common xpath of all the elements within as:

   ```
       List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("common_xpath"));
   ```
4. Next you can even print the size of the list to know the number of elements within the list as follows:

   ```
   int total_count = links.size();
   System.out.println(total_count);
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @Giri If my Answer caters to your Question can you Accept it as a Solution to your Question to Close the discussion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in case you are not receiving any errors with your code and your click is success but is not able to trigger the `javascript`then you may want to make use of `JavascriptExecutor` function as below:

```
   JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor ) driver);
   js.executeScript("javascript:check();");
```

above code will execute the `javascript` function for you.